# How to refresh existing Statusbar notification messages when locale is changed

Tags: android

Please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Statusbar notification messages are shown in X language even after locale language is changed from  X to Y.Please help me what needs to be done to refresh it.
Eg:
Even after changing locale lang from En to Ja , statusbar notification messages are shown in En only i.e The application which is  sending statusbar notification  is run firsttime in En language .

Thanks
Venugopal

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this should work:

Step #1: Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest, watching for `ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`.

Step #2: When your `BroadcastReceiver` is called with `onReceive()`, `cancel()` and re-raise your `Notification`, if your `Notification` is on-screen.

The catch is that you will need to know whether your `Notification` is on-screen or not. That is not very straight-forward. You can try the technique outlined in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev/3630799#3630799), though I have not tried that technique personally. I have filed an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11001) requesting an `isActive()` method for `NotificationManager`, or the equivalent, to help fill this gap.