# Get current notifications android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing for the Android, and
I want to be able to get an array of the current notifications.
For example, say I have two texts and 3 facebook notifications, I want to be able to get a list of what they are, or at least get the type of them.  Is there any possible way to do this with the android api?

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is possible with android 4.3 upwards now

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()

Answer (score 4):

This is **not possible** due to security issues. Its like stealing/intercepting other app's info which is not allowed in framework.

---

## Update

This answer was provided on the basis of facts available till ***Mar 27 '12***.

Comment: Ok, that stinks, could I at least get a boolean of whether there are any notifications or not?

Comment: Sorry, you cant. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev