# Execute code when Android notification is canceled

Tags: android, notifications

I've done some searching and have been unable to find anything even closely related.

When a user cancels a notification in Android (by swiping the notification to one side of the screen), does anyone know of clean way to detect this? I think it would be a rather handy feature in an app to be able to cancel a notification and have the app recognize this and mark something as read in the app instead of clicking the notification and opening the app to mark something as read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev) question today. It looks like the second answer has an interesting solution to detect if a notification is still shown or not. This works for pre API 11 devices. Any device running API 11 or newer can use the [setDeleteIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) to fire a PendingIntent when the notification is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Luke's answer helped me with this. Thanks!

I also found this `setDeleteIntent()` example which I share for everyone's reference.

[how to use delete intent to perform some action on clear notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028122/how-to-use-delete-intent-to-perform-some-action-on-clear-notification)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, how to detect the swipe action for the sliding drawer which is used in the Notification bar, It's not possible dude...

Comment: I think you're talking about opening the notification bar, but my question was about canceling a notification.

Comment: you mean, clearing a notification ?

Comment: yes. clearing, canceling same thing.

Comment: Try Overriding cancel() of NotificationManager class

Comment: I don't think that would be of much use or work. That might be useful if you wanted to do some additional work when you call .cancel() in your app, but I don't think you would be able to discover when the notification was canceled/cleared by the user by overriding it.

Comment: Then, I don't know dude. But I had replied you referring this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/5y9DFmzX79w

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible then...