# is there any listener after performing clear notification in android?

Tags: android

Basicly I want to do something after the user clear my notification from the top bar, How do I do that in andorid programmatically?

Basic example or complete code would be nice thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Notification,setDeleteIntent ，Here is the api:

```
setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent intent)
Supply a PendingIntent to send when the notification is cleared explicitly by the user.
```

Comment: can't you stop your mp3 playing in PendingIntent?

Comment: Hey Gracker You Have My Thanks, and found the way to stop it now. from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028122/how-to-use-delete-intent-to-perform-some-action-on-clear-notification