# Handling Total Count of Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

In my Android app, I keep count of total events and update my notifications accordingly.

I keep track of the events (or message data) in a `List` and the size of the `List` is the running total for pending notifications.  This `List` is initialized in a class that `extends Application`.  So when the app starts (or notification is clicked on), it is reset to zero. A question arises:

W*hat if the User clears the Notification without opening the app.*  The *next* Notification after that will show all `List` data (Think gmail notifications:  It will show the newest message AND the older ones still in the `List`).  **So How/Where can I reset this variable when the user clears a notification?**

FWIW, I am using `Google Cloud Messaging`.

Here is how I handle my Notification now:

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("My App")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(msg))
                            .setLights(0xFF0000, 500, 500)
                            .setNumber(MyApp.events.size())
                            .setContentText(msg);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                    new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("MyApp");
            for (int i=0; i < MyApp.events.size(); i++) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(MyApp.events.get(i));
            }
            if (MyApp.events.size() >= 8) {
                inboxStyle.setSummaryText("+" + (MyApp.events.size() - 7) + " more events.....");
            } else {
                inboxStyle.setSummaryText("Recent Events");
            }
            mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
            mBuilder.setNumber(MyndQuest.events.size());

            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: How do you reset the counter to zero when the notification is clicked on?  I have a counter set up as an int variable in SharedPreferences and I want to reset it to zero when the user clicks on the Notification dropdown shade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working on API 11 or higher you can use `setDeleteIntent(intent)` method for builder. It will supply a `PendingIntent` to send when the notification is cleared explicitly by the user. So you can reset variable.

If you are working on lower API check this: [How to check which notifications are active in status bar in Android Dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev)

Comment: I am targeting API 16+ so this should work...  added code above, fyi

Comment: marked correct; this worked perfect.  Had to set up a Broadcast receiver

Comment: @Misagh Emamverdi How do you reset the counter to zero with setDeleteIntent(intent) when the notification is clicked on? I have a counter set up as an int variable in SharedPreferences and I want to reset it to zero when the user clicks on the Notification dropdown shade.

Comment: @AJW Just as you call `setContentIntent()` and passing a `PendingIntent`, call `setDeleteIntent()` passing a `PendingIntent` that fires a `BroascastReceiver`. In `onReceive()` method, reset your counter value in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Misagh Emamverdi  Ok will try that.  But all of the code I use is within JobIntentService.  So do I set up the BroadcastReceiver as a static inner class within JobIntentService for the PendingIntent?

Comment: @AJW No you can directly create a `PendingIntent` that starts your service as I know.