# How to check if there are any notifications programmatically in android?

Tags: android, notifications

Does anyone know how can I check if there are any notifications programmatically in android?

I want to check if there is any notification currently available in the notifications list.

for example, if there is any notification, the LED light is turned on and if the notifications list is cleared, the LED light is turned off.

I just want to know the condition or the code that allow us to check if there are any notifications available in the notifications list.

if ( condition - there are any notifications )

// my code

Comment: Here is answer: [stack question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev

It is possible since 4.3+

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NotificationListener` API, which is available on Android 4.3+. To do that you just simply need to create a simple `Service` that extends `NotificationListenerService`.

Here is some sample code

```
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;

public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Notification posted");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification Removed");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    }

}
```

A complete tutorial is available [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html)

Prior to this version of Android, you can make a hack through the [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)