# Android Check Notification Existance

Tags: android

I want to check if notification is shown. Because if it is i update it and if it is not i create it but different content. NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications is for >18 api. How can i understand whether notification is there or gone ?

Comment: Do you want to know number of notifiaction shown in notification panel?

Comment: No i just want to know specific notification is exist or gone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630799/639183