# Check which notifications are active in status bar in iPhone using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm newbie to iOS programming and was wondering if we could check which notification are active in iOS using swift.
There's already a question [How to check which notifications are active in status bar in Android Dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630733/how-to-check-which-notifications-are-active-in-status-bar-in-android-dev)
on android, but I'm focussing on iOS. 
Can someone please help me with the same.

Comment: Do you want notifications from your own app or all apps? You can't get notifications for other apps; that would be a privacy violation

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all the notifications active in your Notification tray for iOS.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
    print(notifications)
}
```